# Issue with connecting heroku to custom domain (on GoDaddy)

Tags: heroku

I've created a flask app and hosted it on Heroku. I then followed the heroku documentation on connecting the custom domain, as per link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains.

I added the custom domain of my app to heroku (*.cfoskillset.com) and created a CNAME record on Godaddy with the DNS target that Heroku generated. I waited for about 20 minutes. However, the doain is not working. I am getting an error message: "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" and chrome is saying the connection is not secure.

I searched Stack Overflow for other questions on this, however, none of the replies or solutions worked for me.

What am I doing wrong?

[heroku custom domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juiVb.png)

[goddady dns settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8eUk.png)

Comment: That means that the domain name you are using to visit the site doesn't match the one you on the cert. So you are using "a SSL cert from someone else". So the browser will stop you.